# PayPal GetVerifiedStatus PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to some samples about how to integrate the PayPal GetVerifiedStatus using PHP? I am new to the PayPal API and couldnt find any code samples anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is good library, but you can look here - http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-pro-adaptive-api-class/612#description.

There is demo with video - http://www.binpress.com/app/demo/app/612